# Setting Dynamic arrays equal to eachother in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

```
int staticArrayA[10];
int staticArrayB[10];
int *dynamicArrayA = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * 10);
int *dynamicArrayB = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * 10);
```

From what I understand, the value of staticArrayA is a pointer to the 1st element in the array, however the pointer that represents this base address behaves like a const pointer and cannot be changed, in which case it makes sense that you cannot set:

```
staticArrayA = staticArrayB;
```

But what about dynamic arrays? if they are both just pointers to a contiguous block of bytes in memory, then why can't you set them equal to eachother?

```
dynamicArrayA = dynamicArrayB;
```

It seems like the address that dynamicArrayA points to would now be the same address that dynamicArrayB points to. Please give me some insight. Perhaps I am wrong, but here is what I was trying to do:

```
/* remove any element that is 0 from array. n is size of array */
void compressArray(int *array, int n) {
    int size = n;
    int index = 0;
    int *nuArray = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * n);
    assert(nuArray != NULL);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (array[i] != 0) {
            nuArray[index] = array[i];
            index++;
            size--;
        }
    }
    nuArray = realloc(nuArray, sizeof(int) * size);
    assert(nuArray != NULL);
    array = realloc(array, sizeof(int) * size);
    assert(array != NULL);
    array = nuArray; //This doesn't seem to work
    free(nuArray);
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    int *array = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * 10);
    assert(array != NULL);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            array[i] = 0;
        } else {
            array[i] = i;
        }
    }
    compressArray(array, 10);
    return 0;
}
```

I am sure that there are much simpler and more elegant ways to write the function, and i know that I can copy all the elements of nuArray into array and then use realloc() to reduce the size, however, I am just hoping someone can give some insight into the nature of dynamic arrays and explain some of this behavior and tell me why the assignment does not work, or if there are cases in which it does. Also, i could have the function return an int * and set array = to this function call and that works, however why can't i do it inside the function? Thanks for your time and for any help.

Comment: *But what about dynamic arrays? if they are both just pointers to a contiguous block of bytes in memory, then why can't you set them equal to each other?* You can. But you are just assigning a pointer, a reference, and not copying values of the array. What are you trying to do? Assign values or references?

Comment: It's also needless to use a temp array for this. You can readily remove elements and shift others down.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan do you mind showing me how to do that?

Comment: I can't at this question because you didn't ask that

Comment: @DavidHeffernan  I was trying to remove any 0s in the array. And then just to understand how C works i was wondering why i can't use a temp array and then set that = to the passed in array that i was trying to remove 0s from. I realize now that that wouldnt be smart because i wouldn't be able to free up that memory, but i still dont understand why it wont change the array in main. If inside the function I set the array to point to the same place in memory as the new array, then back in main, why doesnt it print the same values as the temp array if they both point to the same place in memory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's take a look at what's actually happening at the end of `compressArray`:

```
array = nuArray;
```

After this statement, `array` now points to the same memory that `nuArray` points to.  The memory that `array` previously pointed to is now accessible inside of `compressArray`, however `array` in `main` still points to the original memory block.  That's because the address of this block is what was passed to `compressArray`, not the address of the `array` variable.

```
free(nuArray);
```

This frees the memory pointed to by `nuArray`.  But since `array` contains the same value as `nuArray`, i.e. the address of the memory block pointed to by `nuArray`, now `array` points to a freed block of memory, and accessing it is undefined behavior.

When the function returns, the value of `array` in main is unchanged.  That's because the *value* of `array` was passed in.

For this to work as expected, `compressArray` needs to take the address of a pointer (an `int **`) and change what that points to:

```
void compressArray(int **array, int n) {    // "array" is a pointer to an array
    int size = n;
    int index = 0;
    int *nuArray = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * n);
    assert(nuArray != NULL);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if ((*array)[i] != 0) {            // note how we're now accessing the array
            nuArray[index] = (*array)[i];  // same here
            index++;
            size--;
        }
    }
    nuArray = realloc(nuArray, sizeof(int) * size);
    assert(nuArray != NULL);
    free(*array);     // We don't need the memory array pointed to anymore, so free it
    *array = nuArray; // This changes "array" in main.  Also, don't free nuArray, 
                      // otherwise *array will also point to freed memory
}
```

Then you call it like this:

```
compressArray(&array, 10);
// print the new contents of array
free(array);    // We're done with it now, so free it
```

Answer (score 2):

> if they are both just pointers to a contiguous block of bytes in memory, then why can't you set them equal to each other?

Of course you can. You just have to know the ramifications.

```
int *dynamicArrayA = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * 10);
int *dynamicArrayB = dynamicArrayA;
```

Now `dynamicArrayB` and `dynamicArrayA` point to the same memory. You change the value of what one points to, the change will be visible through other pointer too.

```
dynamicArrayB[0] = 10; // dynamicArrayA[0] is 10.
dynamicArrayA[5] = 15; // dynamicArrayB[5] is 15.
```

If that's your objective, you can do that without any problem.

**Update, in response to OP's comment**

The line

```
array = nuArray; //This doesn't seem to work
```

changes the value of `array` locally in `compressArray`. That does not change the value of `array` in `main`.

You'll have to come up with a different method to return `nuArray` back to `main`.

One solution to the problem would be to change the return type of `compressArray` from `void` to `char*` and return `nuArray` from the function.

Comment: ok, but when i test out the code, the compressArray function does not change the array I allocated in main.

Answer (score 1):

```
int *dynamicArrayA = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * 10);
int *dynamicArrayB = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * 10);
```

After this if you do this ( *which ofcourse is possible* ) -

```
dynamicArrayA = dynamicArrayB;  //you want this then don't allocate memory to dynamicArrayA
```

Now , `dynamicArrayA` won't point to memory allocate by `malloc` to it previously , so you won't be able to `free` that memory block . Thus , can lead to memory leak.

You can use `memcpy` for this task -

```
/* allocate memory to both dynamicArrayA and to dynamicArrayB */
for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
   dynamicArrayA[i]=i+1;       // store value in dynamicArrayA
}
memcpy(dynamicArrayB,dynamicArrayA,sizeof(int)*10);   //copy it to dynamicArrayB

for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
  printf("%d",dynamicArrayB[i]);        // print values 

free(dynamicArrayA);
free(dynamicArrayB);
```

Comment: ok thanks, so it wouldnt be smart to do that anyways because i would have lost that allocated memory in the heap.

Comment: @crypt3c Yes, if you want to do that then don't allocate memory to pointer which points to other one , then there wont be such problem .

Comment: @crypt3c When you allocate memory dynamically, you have 2 primary responsibilities regarding that block of memory: (1) preserve a pointer to the beginning address of the block of memory so (2) it can be freed when no longer needed. In this example `dynamicArrayA = dynamicArrayB;` violates rule (1) (e.g. the address for the block originally pointed to by `dynamicArrayA` is lost) which prevents you from ever being able to take care of rule (2).